# Sending example files to RailsAPI to test it's workflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-api

So I have finished my `Rails API` and the testing of it using `RSpec` and `FactoryGirl`. This API is made to store incoming files in a `PostgreSQL` database and it does not have any views, only models and controllers. Now I want to see it working so I will start it and I want to send a few example files to see how it truly behaves with "real" data.

How can I achieve this? I mean, simulate real incoming data and test the `Create`, `Update`, etc. actions. I've been looking for a while and I really have no idea where to start from so any clue would be nice.

NOTE:
To help you understand what I mean, if I had a normal `Rails` project, I would use the new.html.rb page to `create` a new record, the edit.html.rb to `update` an existing one, etc. This is what I would like to work with, but with no html forms/pages, just a couple of files that I want to load into the database and play with my `API` in development mode before it goes to Production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Chrome, you can take a look at the [Postman plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client) plugin.

If you are on mac or linux, you can also use [curl from the command line](http://blogs.plexibus.com/2009/01/15/rest-esting-with-curl/).

I am pretty sure there are similar tools for windows.

If nothing else works, you can create some simple, static HTML pages with forms on them.

Comment: I've tried postman and it seem to be suitable for what I want. I'm just having trouble in creating an hash with the exact values I need, but it's just a matter of digging a little more. Thanks!